# Rotate SVG layer and adjust viewbox

Tags: html, svg

I'm really struggling to get my head around this... I'm trying to rotate a bunch of SVGs through 90 degrees. There will be one or more of these displayed on the same web page, and I'd like them to more-or-less fill a page each when printed.

I've not generated the SVGs and they are supplied with a strange viewBox setting. The entire thing seems to be contained in a single layer, so if I apply a `transform = "rotate(90 0 0)"` to that layer, it does indeed rotate -- but it doesn't remain in the viewBox.

I may be getting the terminology wrong, but I've setup a Fiddle with an example of one of the SVGs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/CYZve/1/).

I'm planning to adjust the attributes using jQuery, which I know works -- I just don't know what to change!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third parameters of the rotate operation are the x and y of the center of rotation. Try setting them to the centre point of the viewBox.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of knew that, but I needed to do quite a lot of trial-and-error to get the correct viewBox / rotate combination. I've now managed to get the SVGs to rotate correctly (it just took longer than I'd hoped).